# Give an example of an infinite disjoint sequence of subsets of the real numbers, each of which is of second category in the real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, baire-category

The imperative in the title is Exercise 21.12 from Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus, Second Edition, written by Kenneth Ross. (page 178)

I have searched on this website for "elementary analysis 21.12" and "infinite disjoint sequence second category" but didn't find anything that seemed relevant.

For context, this question follows a section that stated and proved the Baire Category Theorem.

My problem:

I wanted to give the example $(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), \dots$ but I am not quite sure if these sets are of second category in $\mathbb{R}$. I think they are, because none of them be written as the union of a sequence of nowhere dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. (Informally, you cannot union a countable number of single points to create an interval.)

I found what purports to be a solution at the link https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781461462705-elementary-analysis-the-theory-of-calculus-2nd-edition/178/exercises/12/#, but the answer given is $U_n = \mathbb{Q} \setminus [n, n + 1)$ for $n = 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, \dots$. This seems overly elaborate, and I'm not even sure if it meets the criteria since it doesn't look to me like the sets $U_n$ are disjoint.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks.

Comment: Your example is fine. But proving it  requires more than facts about "a countable union of single points" because a nowhere dense set can be way bigger than a single point. For example, the Cantor set is nowhere dense. If you don't already know the Baire category theorem, you should look it up; it makes the proof easy.  (The $U_n$'s that you found on the web are wrong, not only because they're not pairwise disjoint but also because every one of them is a subset of the countable set $\mathbb Q$ and is therefore of first category.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Pages 172-173 have five formulations of the BCT---I am not sure which one to use. Let me make an attempt. I will use the formulation "The union of a sequence of nowhere dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ has dense complement." Assume that $(n, n+1)$ is of first category. That means it can be written as the union of a sequence of nowhere dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. By the aforementioned formulation of the BCT, this means that the complement $\mathbb{R} \setminus (n, n+1)$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. This is clearly false, so we conclude that $(n, n+1)$ is of second category.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess I'll submit my proof as an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sets $(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), \dots$ are clearly disjoint. We want to prove that they are of second category in $\mathbb{R}$.

We will assume that the set $(n, n + 1)$---where $n$ is a non-negative integer---is of first category in $\mathbb{R}$ and find a contradiction. This proof uses the Baire Category Theorem in the formulation "the union of a sequence of nowhere dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ has dense complement." It also uses the definition of a set of first category, which is that a set is of first category in $\mathbb{R}$ if can be written as the union of a sequence of nowhere dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. (Category 2 sets are all sets not in Category 1.)

Assume $(n, n + 1)$ is of first category in $\mathbb{R}$. Using the definition of a set of first category, we see that $(n, n + 1)$ can be written as the union of a sequence of nowhere dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. By the aforementioned formulation of the BCT, the complement $\mathbb{R} \setminus (n,n+1)$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. This is clearly false, so we conclude that $(n,n+1)$ is of second category.

Postscript: This proof seems to show that any non-degenerate interval of finite length is of second category in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: +1.... If $\emptyset \ne B\subset A\subset \Bbb R$ and $B$ is open in $\Bbb R$ then $A$ is 2nd category in $\Bbb R.$  For if $A=\cup F$ where $F$ is a countable family of nowhere-dense subsets of $\Bbb R$ then $\Bbb R$ \ $A=\Bbb R$ \ $\cup F$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, which is absurd because $\Bbb R$ \ $A$ is disjoint from the non-empty open set $B.$